# CSS height percentage not scaling image

Tags: css

I'm trying to create the top portion of a website to hold a logo on the left and a nav bar on the right. The image is large because I was told it might be used on a HDTV and wanted it to scale well. I thought if I put the logo and a nav bar in the same div i could just apply a percentage to the height so it would always be the top 10% of the screen but it doesn't scale with my code, it just stays the same image size. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="5">5</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS im using

```
#top {
height: 10%;
width: 100%
}
```

I would really appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to scale the image itself, you need to target the image in your CSS.

I would also recommend setting a minimum (and possibly maximum) limit to your scaling. There is a point where getting smaller will just look bad and become unusable.

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#top {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 23px;
}

#top img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 23px;
    min-width: 136px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvgtX/2/)

Comment: That actually seems to make it bigger, but at least it scaled. Any other idea?

Comment: @user2093601 The image scales within the 10% frame in my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JvgtX/show/). What exactly is not working?

Comment: Ah sorry the example code in stackoverflow showed img height:100% not 10%. Your right though, the JS fiddle example does work with the 10% height applied to the img element. Shouldn't the img element take on the property of the parent top div and adjust? That is to say why wouldn't I be able to make the containing div 'top' 10% and have the img inherit that size property?

Comment: @user2093601 [CSS height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height) is not an inherited property.

Comment: Would you say I'm off to a bad start with the way I'm structuring my html? Essentially I would like the top just to be the image and the nav bar centered with the nav bar to the right of the image. All of that to take up a 10% of the screen regardless of size.

Comment: @user2093601 I think what you are trying to accomplish is reasonable. I actually made an assumption in my original example that I have since corrected. When you are using percentages, you have to ensure that your `html` and `body` containers are explicitly set up to take up a set amount of space. Otherwise there might be unexpected behavior and certain browsers may behave differently. Now setting the `img` height to `100%` of its parent works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the image a height of 10% so that it knows to scale with the div. I believe it will work if you do that.

```
#top img {
    height: 10%;
}
```

Edit: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZB7C/)

Comment: That does make it scale. Shouldn't the image inherit the property of the div so I could assign it 100%?

Comment: It is floated so the `#top` is actually empty (height: 0px) as float takes elements out of the normal flow.

Comment: This is presuming you want to float the contents of `#top` of course.

Comment: If i could pick your brain then how would you set your properties if you would like the image and nav bar be in the center of the screen with the nav bar to the right of the image not under it?